Replace NaN by None by without raise SettingWithCopyWarning
I have a data frame looking of this:
       x    u    i  rowid
0    1.0  1.0  5.0    1.0
1    2.0  2.0  4.0    2.0
2    3.0  3.0  3.0    3.0
3    4.0  4.0  2.0    NaN
4    5.0  5.0  1.0    5.0
5    6.0  4.0  0.0    6.0
6    7.0  3.0  1.0    7.0
7    8.0  2.0  2.0    NaN
8    9.0  1.0  3.0    9.0
9   10.0  0.0  4.0   10.0
10  11.0  1.0  5.0   11.0
11  12.0  2.0  3.0   12.0
12  13.0  3.0  2.0    NaN
13  14.0  4.0  1.0   14.0
14  15.0  5.0  0.0   15.0
16  17.0  3.0  2.0   17.0

I need to replace Nan with None in rowid column. I'm doing this with:
data_frame = data_frame.where(pandas.notnull(data_frame), None)

But, this raise a:
/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1843: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

I read a lot of docs and other questions without success. The closest solution I found is:
data_frame.loc[numpy.isnan(data_frame[ROW_ID]), ROW_ID] = None

It don't work (data_frame is the same). But I know I'm close because when replacing None by -1, Nan are replaced by -1.
Any idea ?

Note: When use .replace, .where and inplace=True (from other solutions) I always got the SettingWithCopyWarning.

None is not a number, so this will change the dtype of the column.  This change can't be done inplace.

The comment above is right about the type of convertion, even trough, have you ever try with the isna() function? instead of isnan().
This should make the magic:
data_frame.loc[pd.isna(data_frame['rowid']), 'rowid'] = None

If you still encounter issues, it might be because 'rowid' is of a numeric type that doesn't support None. In that case, you can convert it to object type first:
data_frame['rowid'] = data_frame['rowid'].astype('object')
data_frame.loc[pd.isna(data_frame['rowid']), 'rowid'] = None


isna don't make the trick (NaN still in dataframe). Using astype correctly change to None, but throw SettingWithCopyWarning.

This answer should be very useful for your warning. How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas
